# Generating json data file from oracle 10g database using sql

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle10g, json-api

I want to know how can I create a JSON API through which I can get Oracle 10g data using SQL in JSON format.

I know that JSON_Object are introduced in Oracle 12C R2 but I have Oracle 10g and I want to get data from my Oracle 10g database in JSON format.

Comment: Please read [How to ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Deepak.Pal Since you have overriden my removal of json-api tag, please have a look at JSON API specification: http://jsonapi.org/ Sending JSON over an REST API is not the same as implementing the spec. Please rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PLJSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) package. I used it in one project and it worked fine for me.